# Django south migration - column cannot be cast to type integer

Tags: django, django-south

```
class Stop(models.Model):
    geo_region = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
```

I need to change the field type to a foreign key in this class, keeping the data. So I made the below class and did the `schemamigration` and `datamigration` to save the geo_name values into the new table.

```
class GeoRegion(models.Model):
    geo_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name=u'Name')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.name
```

And I changed the field type of the geo_region.

```
class Stop(models.Model):
    geo_region = models.ForeignKey(GeoRegion)
```

Then I run the `south schemamigration` command again and got an error;

```
DatabaseError: column "geo_region_id" cannot be cast to type integer
```

How can I resolve this issue out and match the existing geo_name values to the new foreign key?

Comment: This : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179063/cannot-be-cast-to-type-integer-error is not an accepted answer, but should give you an idea..

Comment: I already reviewed it and saved the old data into the GeoRegion table. The problem is the next DatabaseError I mentioned and how to match the values to the new foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by the below datamigration and then schemamigration to convert the charfield to foreignkey.

```
class Migration(DataMigration):

def forwards(self, orm):
    for region in orm['runs.Stop'].objects.distinct('geo_region'):
        orm['runs.GeoRegion'].objects.create(geo_name=region.geo_region)
    db.start_transaction()
    db.add_column('runs_stop', 'geo_region_tmp', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.IntegerField')(default=0), keep_default=False)
    db.commit_transaction()
    db.start_transaction()
    db.execute('Update runs_stop AS R SET geo_region_tmp=s.id FROM runs_georegion S WHERE S.geo_name=R.geo_region')
    db.delete_column('runs_stop', 'geo_region')
    db.add_column('runs_stop', 'geo_region', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.IntegerField')(default=0), keep_default=False)
    db.commit_transaction()
    db.start_transaction()
    db.execute('Update runs_stop SET geo_region=geo_region_tmp')
    db.delete_column('runs_stop', 'geo_region_tmp')
    db.commit_transaction()
```

Answer (score -1):

You have old data in your `Stop` database table under the `geo_region` field. South is taking that data and trying to put it into the new `models.ForeignKey()` field (which is expecting an instance of the geo_region model). You need to write a data migration (see, for example, the [South documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html)) that either gets rid of the old data, or converts it, something like:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    for stop in orm.Stop.objects.all():
        geo_region = GeoRegion.objects.get(geo_name=stop.geo_region)
        stop.geo_region = geo_region
        stop.save()
```

untested code, but it should be similar. You might also want to write a `backwards()` method.

Comment: I already saved the old data into the GeoRegion table. The problem is the next DatabaseError I mentioned and how to match the values to the new foreign key.

Comment: Right. So the problem is the `Chars` that are currently in `stop.geo_region`

Comment: The data migration I posted is describing how to match the values to the new foreign key. Take a look at the south documentation I posted. Your problem is that you have records in your `Stop` table that have `chars` in and South doesn't know how to convert them to foreign keys by itself.

Comment: you are right, Pete. So I am asking how to resolve the problem.

Comment: The south documentation I posted as well as my answer both explain how to resolve this problem.